# EditText editing Box

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to give user options to make text style like in
this image in edittext (option for bold italic and Normal).First User select the text then on clicking  button changing the textStyle of text written in EditText.
: 
[image]

This is code

```
public class Addnew extends Activity {
Spinner spinner;
String select=null;
private String selec(String selected){
    return selected;

}

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addnew);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.comptypeinput);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spin= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Addnew.this,R.array.spinner,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spin.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(spin);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        String selected = null;
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            selected = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            select = selec(selected);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(Addnew.this, "Please Select Complaint Type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText comptimee= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timeinput);
            EditText compaddresse= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressinput);
            EditText compdesce = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptioninput);
            String username= getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
            String comptime = comptimee.getText().toString();
            String compaddress = compaddresse.getText().toString();
            String compdesc = compdesce.getText().toString();
            AddnewAsync as=new AddnewAsync();
            as.execute(select,comptime,compdesc,compaddress,username);
        }
    });
}

private class AddnewAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private Dialog pd ;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comp_type", params[0]));
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("availtime", params[1]));
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", params[2]));
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", params[3]));
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[4]));
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost hp = new HttpPost("http://172.31.144.231/test/andcompinsert.php");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String result=null;
        try {
            hp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
            HttpResponse response = hc.execute(hp);
            HttpEntity ent= response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = ent.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = null;
            while((line=reader.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
             result = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(Addnew.this, "Please Wait", "Uploading");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pd.dismiss();
        String s = result.trim();
        if(s.equals("success")){
            Toast.makeText(Addnew.this, "Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent inten = new Intent(Addnew.this,PreviousComp.class);
            String username= getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
            inten.putExtra("user", username);
            startActivity(inten);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(Addnew.this, "Error Updating... Please Try Again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```

In my edittext compdesce i want that options.

Comment: Can we see your code where you are attempting to write to a database, please?

Comment: i Am using asyctask to send http requests and save it in database. nothing special is there. Just a simple edittext and a button to executte asyctask @blahfunk

Comment: All you have shown us is what you want to do. You are not showing us any code to be able to help you. We won't write your code for you, but we can help correct the code you have written. May we please please please see your code that you are using to write to the database since that is where the error is occurring?

Comment: @blahfunk Here it is.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i dont get any error. i have no clue how to do that. so i havent done with my edittext anything @blahfunk

Comment: No clue, yet you send it's contents to `http://172.31.144.231/test/andcompinsert.php` ? Why not ask your backend guy how to save stuff to that database?

Comment: No no !! u r getting it wrong. I want to provide options for bold italic etc in edit text.

Comment: you must save your text using html tags or isert som elements in your text like stackOverflow . for example stack insert ** before and after bold , save complete text and when you need to show text use your elements for detect styles

Comment: @blahfunk I have updated my question.

Comment: @bryanc can u give an example code

Comment: @Mayank i will but it takes som minutes

Comment: @bryanc Not a single prob. Thanks By the way. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use html tags like `<b> </b>` and etc for styling text text entered in an edittext and set text of a TextView:

```
final TextView txView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final EditText txtEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str=txtEdit.getText().toString();
            txView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
        }
    });
}
```

if you enter text like "its a `<b>`bold text`</b>` " in your editText result will be:
"its a **bold text**"